# Finding the maximum score of a PostTypeId for each post - data explorer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dataexplorer

I am trying to create a query that will display each user's post Id, PostTypeId, and the maximum score for that posts' type.

For example, for all posts that are questions (PostTypeId = 1) then the maximum score column for all rows where (PostTypeId = 1) will be "22363".

So far I am only getting a table of each posts' score and sorting by DESC to get the maximum score. I see that the maximum score for a question is 22363 and I want to display this number for all questions.

```
SELECT 
    TOP 100
    Users.Id,
    DisplayName,
    PostTypeId, 
    MAX(CAST(Score AS float)) AS MaxAnswerScore
FROM
    Posts
  INNER JOIN
    Users ON Users.Id = OwnerUserId
GROUP BY
    Users.Id, DisplayName, PostTypeId
ORDER BY
    MaxAnswerScore DESC
```

I'm trying to do this for all PostTypeIds, not just questions.

[Current implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nd8s.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to assign each row a number by the maximum score descending partitioned by the user. Then only take the first record.

```
SELECT x.id,
       x.displayname,
       x.posttypeid,
       x.score
       FROM (SELECT u.id,
                    u.displayname,
                    p.posttypeid,
                    max(cast(score AS float)) score,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY u.id
                                       ORDER BY max(cast(score AS float)) DESC) rn
                    FROM users u
                         INNER JOIN posts p
                                    ON p.owneruserid = u.id
                    GROUP BY u.id,
                             u.displayname,
                             p.posttypeid) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1
       ORDER BY x.score DESC;
```

If you want to see ties, i.e. if a user has their top score in more than one post type, replace `row_number()` with `rank()`.

---

Edit:

Still not sure what you want, but let's give it another shot:

```
SELECT u1.id,
       u1.displayname,
       p1.posttypeid,
       max(cast(p1.score AS float)) score,
       (SELECT max(cast(p2.score AS float))
               FROM posts p2
               WHERE p2.posttypeid = p1.posttypeid) maximumscore
       FROM users u1
            INNER JOIN posts p1
                       ON p1.owneruserid = u1.id
       GROUP BY u1.id,
                u1.displayname,
                p1.posttypeid
       ORDER BY p1.posttypeid,
                max(cast(p1.score AS float)) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your query is still not assigning a maximum score by type, it's still just getting the max score of a post. https://imgur.com/a/W6vZFbn

Comment: Hhm, I might not get this right. If you change `PARTITION BY u.id` to `PARTITION BY p.posttypeid`, does that give you what you want? If not, does `PARTITION BY u.id, p.posttypeid` work for you?

Comment: Nope, none of them work. :-( It should look like this. https://imgur.com/a/WCugF7h

Comment: Here's the current query that can be run on data explorer: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/954715

Comment: @mel: Sorry but I don't get what you want I'm afraid: Can you edit your question and add an example for given input and expected output? Maybe that helps.

Comment: The edit is exactly it! Thanks for all the help, sticky bit. Sorry for the confusion, I'm a new user and I'm still getting used to post etiquette.